# Websphere and Tomcat custom error file right directory

Tags: tomcat, websphere, http-status-code-404

I have set the following into my `web.xml` for both Websphere and Tomcat:

```xml
  <error-page>
      <error-code>404</error-code>
      <location>/error404.html</location>
  </error-page>
```

But somehow I am not sure where to put the `error-404.html` page! Its not being picked up by Websphere or Tomcat (I am testing on both servers on different servers).

Can anyone please instruct me on this? Is this configuration enough or are other configurations are also needed to set a custom error page for 404, 403, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Servlet 3.0 spec says:

> The error-page contains a mapping between an error code or an exception type 
>   to the path of a resource in the Web application. The sub-element exceptiontype contains a fully qualified class name of a Java exception type. The sub-element `location` element contains the location of the resource in the web 
>   application relative to the root of the web application. The value of the location 
>   must have a leading ‘/’.

So for the location `/error404.html` you should put `error404.html` in the application root (next to, but not inside, the `WEB-INF` directory).

Comment: Thanks , will try and update the issue. Do u have any idea about tomcat as well? thanks

Comment: This should work for Tomcat and WebSphere, as well as any other application server that fulfills the Servlet specification.